# SDK php , add news in Public wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

I try to publish news on my wall (for everyone ), but my program doesn't work, can you help me please ?

```
            $app_config = array(
                'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'cookie' => true
            );
            $page_config = array(
                'access_token' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'page_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            );


            $facebook = new Facebook($app_config);


            $privacy=array('value' => 'EVERYONE');
            $decri=array('name' => 'See the link', 'link' => 'http://www.xxxxxx.com');
            $description="this is a test";
            $picture="a.png";

            $params = array(
             'access_token' => $page_config['access_token'],
             'name' => $title,
             'caption' => 'www.xxxxxx.com',
             'link' => 'http://www.xxxxxx.com',
             'description' => $description,
             'picture' => $picture,
             'status_type' => 'mobile_status_update',
             'type' => 'status',
             'privacy' => json_encode($privacy),
             'actions' => json_encode($decri)
            );

            $post_id = $facebook->api('/'.$page_config['page_id'].'/feed','post',$params);
```

But nothing is published , i don't understand
Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I assume you're posting to a Facebook page - and, in this case, especially a link.

When you try to publish links, you don't post them to `/PAGE_ID/feed`, you post them to `/PAGE_ID/links` (see [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page#feed)).

In your example, your API request should look like this:

```
$post_id = $facebook->api('/'.$page_config['page_id'].'/links','post',$params);
```

Also, `$picture` is supposed to be a link, beginning with `http` or `https`.

Last but not least make sure, you have the `publish_stream` and the `manage_pages` permissions.

Compared to the documentation, there are slight differences in the parameters you use, so please double-check the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page#feed) - it seems you're doing too much work.